# Why does this List Comprehension work but not the for loop for creating a grid copy?

Tags: python, list

I am confused why the below works but the following does not?

Input:

```
grid = [[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]
```

Working:

```
def foo(grid):
    m = len(grid)
    n = len(grid[0])
    gridCopy = [[grid[row][col] for col in range(n)] for row in range(m)]
    return gridCopy == grid
```

Does not work:

```
def bar(grid):
    m = len(grid)
    n = len(grid[0])
    gridCopy = [[None] * n] * m
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            gridCopy[i][j] = grid[i][j]
    return gridCopy == grid
```

I get the following grid returned from `bar()`:

```
gridCopy = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `[[None] * n] * m`?

Comment: You have `i` and `j` and `m` and `n` muddled

Comment: @jasonharper thank you! that's it! This was my original question, the swapped variables were a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You swapped the lengths for each array.

Instead of

```
gridCopy = [[None] * m] * n
```

Try

```
gridCopy = [[None] * n] * m
```

Comment: Swapping this results in grid:
```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```